Cassandra datastax 3.11.5 compatability
I have used datastax driver 3.11.5 version to connect to cassadra instance in version 4.x .Is this compatable ?
Also when I am using EmbeddedCassandraServiceHelper from cassandra-unit version 4.3.1.0 for junit testing. Getting error :

Test.java:[38,58] error: incompatible types: CqlSession cannot be converted to Session
Test.java:[38,66] error: incompatible types: CqlSession cannot be converted to Session

       @Before
    public void setUp() {
        session = EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.getSession();
        dao = new CompressingDataDao<>(session, XY.class);
    }
 @Test
    public void getOne() throws Exception {
        String id = "abc";
        XY list = createAndSaveEnitty(id);

        XY listFromDB = dao.getOne(id);

        Assert.assertEquals(list, listFromDB);
    }


If driver 3.11.5 is compatable with cassandra version 4, How to do Unit testing as above method is giving error.


Can anyone helpout

Cassandra Java Driver 3.11 is compatible with Cassandra 4. But cassandra-unit is using Cassandra Java Driver 4.x. So it seems to me that your dependency is messed up.
Cassandra Java Driver 4.x used modern designs and introduced a lot of breaking changes. Cassandra Java Driver 3.x is not maintained anymore. I would recommend you to upgrade your driver to 4.x.
